# I am trying to update php 5.5.38 to 7.1 using "curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0"

Tags: php, macos

I pasted `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0` to my terminal to update PHP 5.5.38 to 7.0 but I am receiving problems like SIGHUP or SIGTERM.

[image: Screenshot]

What should I do to update my PHP? Are there any other methods to update?

Comment: with "curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1 " same problem arise

Comment: I've never heard of `php-osx.liip.ch`.  I normally use [homebrew](https://brew.sh) for these things, PHP7 may be in there.

Comment: If you do use homebrew, you'll need this "tap": https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php

Comment: I removed all the code that I had written in "nano .bash_profile" command and save it using "control x" and refreshed whole using source .bash_profile than the above code works: